# Text animation when hovering [part 2]

Tags: css

Previously asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28977694/text-animation-when-hovering-over-an-image) for some help in regards to fading in some text when hovering over an image, as I couldn't figure out how to make the text float above the images.

Now I've figured it out on my own, but I'm still having issues with the text itself.

You can see a live version of the page [here](http://vengefulchip.tk/playground/index.html).

What it currently does is it positions every sentence in each language in distinctive rows. What I would like it to do is to show all the lines at a specific point on the page (below the logo, and above the flags)

Also it seems that when I hover the mouse over where the sentences are, they fade in, while I wanted that to happen only when hovering over the flags.

```
#en { 
    height: 150px;
    line-height: 0px; 
    color: transparent; 
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
    font-weight: 300; 
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease; 
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease; 
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease; 
} 

#en:hover { 
    line-height: 150px; 
    line-height: 20px; 
    color: #e0e0e0;
} 

#en img{ 
    width: 118px;
    height: 78px;
    position: absolute;
    float: bottom;
    clear: bottom;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 29.8%;
    }
```

Here's the code on jsfiddle as somebody asked for it last time:
https://jsfiddle.net/f0gfqe6e/4/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `“HelveticaNeue-Light”`. Looks like typographic quotes copy-pasted from a document. Consider replacing them with `"` or `'`.

Comment: Whops, can't believe that slipped me. Fixed it.

Comment: Fixed here in the other thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28977694/text-animation-when-hovering-over-an-image?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

here you go just put the color as transparent on hover over text

---

```
<div id="en" class="en">Welcome to Stefan's Gallery, click to proceed to the english version of the site.
                <span><a href="./en/"><img src="en.png" width="118" /></a></span>
```

CSS

```
 .en:hover { 
         color: transparent;
    }
```

just give the same to remaining text fields too.

Comment: Thanks, but that prevents the text from appearing when I hover on the image too :)   EDIT: Nevermind, just saw your edit now, now instead it doesn't hide the text :S

Answer (score 0):

I would try making the text a child of the flag and then set the flags to relative position (also probably inline-block from the look of it) and the children to absolute and all at the same top property.  Then use this kind of CSS:

```
#en-flag > span {
   opacity:0;
   transition:1s;
}

#en-flag:hover > span {
   opacity:1;
}
```

Since the flags are just images, you can make them background images so the div can be empty for the span.